# PDE Steady State Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the problem
$u_t$ = $u_{xx}$ − $au$  0< x <1, t>0, a=constant≠0
$u(x,0) = f(x)$ 0 < x < 1
$u(0,t) = 0$, $u(1, t)$ = 0 t > 0.
(a) If a > 0, what are the possible steady state solutions?
(b) Solve the time-dependent problem via separation of variables method when a > 0. What happens to the solution as
$t → ∞$?
(c) If a < 0, what are the possible steady state solutions?

In class, we have only done problems with $u_t$ = $u_{xx}$ so I am not sure how to do it with the $-au$ attached.

Comment: Steady state implies that time derivatives are zero, so what would become the differential equation in that case?

Comment: So that means au = u_xx ?

Comment: Yes, however often steady state is also often similar to the solution as $t\to\infty$, if the system is stable.